# How to set selectable maximum month in mtz.monthpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

(edited)

I'm using jquery.mtz.monthpicker with jquery.

I wanna restrict future month, but I think there's no options like 'maxDate' in jquery.ui.datepicker.

```
$('input[name*="from"]').monthpicker({startYear:1970,finalYear:<?=date('Y')?>,pattern:'yyyy-mm'}).bind('monthpicker-show', function (e, year) {
    $('input[name*="from"]').monthpicker('disableMonths', []); // (re)enables all
    if (year === <?=date('Y')?> ) {

        var curMonth = <?=date('n')?>;
        var months = new Array();
        var j = 0;
        for (var i = curMonth+1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
                months[j++] = i;
        }

        $('input[name*="from"]').monthpicker('disableMonths', months);
    }
});
```

I coded like this. only can select current, and past months. but it doesn't works. 
what is the problem?

Comment: show what have you tried ?

Comment: Are you getting errors on the JS Console? I think you might want to quote the year/month, i.e. `'<?=date('Y')?>'`. Also you might want to bind to `monthpicker-change-year` instead of / as well as just `monthpicker-show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var months = new Array();
var j = 0;
for (var i = <?=date('n')?>+1; i <= 12; i++)
{
        months[j++] = i;
}

$('input[name*="from"]').monthpicker({startYear:1970,finalYear:<?=date('Y')?>,pattern:'yyyy-mm'});
for(var i = 0; i < $('input[name*="from"]').length; i++){
$($('input[name*="from"]')[i]).monthpicker("disableMonths",months);
$($('input[name*="from"]')[i]).monthpicker().bind('monthpicker-change-year', function(e, year){

    var item = $(e.currentTarget);
    if(year === '<?=date("Y")?>'){
     $(item).monthpicker('disableMonths', months);
    } else {
    $(item).monthpicker('disableMonths', []);
    }
});
}
```

I solved.

First of all, removed method chain.

Second, monthpicker-show event has no 'year' parameter.

I think there were key points.